# Why is there no ListView available in my Toolbox when I develop my Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a `ListView` to my `.xaml` file but I can't seem to find any `ListView` in the `Toolbox` provided in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default `ListView` control in Windows Phone 8, may be you can use `LongListSelector` instead. Here is a list of controls with a brief description to help you [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402561%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I notice it was just my clumsy error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ListBox` or `LongListSelector` control.

Comment: ListBox is considered to be deprecated. LongListSelector is the recommended control to replace WinRT "ListView".

Comment: Yes.In windows phone 8.1 LongListSelector is now SemanticZoom [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-what-controls-are-new.aspx). may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListBox` and also the `LongListSelector` as @Vyas_27 suggests.

Your can find information about the `ListBox` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

LongListSelector is available in this namespace:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` and the `LongListSelector` can be used like this:

```
<ListBox />
<phone:LongListSelector />
```

As Gaurav pointed out, for the `LongListSelector` you'll need to have the following namespace declaration in your .xaml file.

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```